# Blender: Setting additional properties per face

Tags: blender, 3d-meshes, export

I wish to use Blender to model level for 3D game.
Level is a set of Meshes.
I have to set special (additional) properties per face (triangle).
These properties are like integer number or vector or color.

Ideally I would select a set of faces and set TAG1 to be 7 and TAG2 to be (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) and TAG3 to be Red for these faces.

- TAG1 is Integer
- TAG2 is Vector
- TAG2 is Color

Also I would like to be able to export that model in some format like Collada or OBJ.
I use ASSIMP to convert model in my game internal format.

I believe OBJ does not support extra properties.

It sounds like very common task for gamedev. But I can't find any simple solution that does not require to create my own 3D editing tool.

Also I can consider using other 3D modelling tool if it has such functionality.

Comment: You can create a material named "`7_1.0,0.0,0.0_Red`" and apply it to the face, then parse it while importing the object. Or Blender has some very advanced scripting tools. Remember that we do have a [Blender SE](http://blender.stackexchange.com/?as=1) if you want to ask specific Blender questions. How to set custom properties per face and export those might be a good question there. Please don't cross post though (if you want to ask this same question there, remove it from here).

Comment: I need original materials as well. If I will have 2 same models with different materials then when I will export models to OBJ or Collada then it will split meshes differently. Every mesh has 1 material when you export it. I will think about it. It will require to rebuild meshes in my app after exporting from blender. I think such work compares with making simple 3D editor

Comment: There are likely material properties you could use (or abuse) to suit your purposes. Materials are most likely the easiest way to get something like this done, because they attach information to each face. As I said, you might want to ask the people over at the Blender SE if any such properties exist.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Blender. It's also been cross posted on the Blender stack exchange already.